# Why does my chemistry recipe not work?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-education-edition

[image: recipe1 green] [image] The Minecraft Education Edition involves chemistry, allowing you to create different chemicals.

[Here](https://education.minecraft.net/wp-content/uploads/ChemistryLab_Journal.pdf) is a PDF listing all the different things you can make with Chemistry.  I used a Mercuric Chloride recipe to create a Red Torch. But it didn't work.

I used Tungsten instead and it somehow works, creating a Green Torch! But all I did was use different chemicals! Why does the Green Torch recipe work but not the Red Torch?

I'm on Minecraft for Nintendo Switch, 1.16.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.16.1 is quite an outdated version. There were many minor fixes and improvements over the times. The current version is 1.16.20.

Try updating to the latest version and see if it works.